# How to color (fill) barplot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

looks like easy to solve (i'm beginner using R), i've tried `scale_fill_manual`, but for some reason doesn't work.

here's the code:

```
st<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=ES, y=Count.of.ID))
    st+geom_bar(stat = "identity",  na.rm=TRUE, colour = "black") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green")) + 
coord_flip() + 
theme_classic() + 
facet_grid(ES.Types~., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

i want to color the bars related to:

- "cultural" in Red
- "P" in Yellow
- "Regulating" in Green
- "Supply" in Blue

Thx in advance

Comment: You need to map `fill` to the variable you want to color by.  Which is possibly `ES.Types`?  Some good starting resources for getting started with ggplot2 are the [Graphs section of Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) and the [ggplot2 book](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)

# some fake data
df2 <- data.frame(ES = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 2),
                 Count.of.ID = rep(1:5, 2),
                 ES.Types = rep(c("Poor", "Rich"), 5))
# use ES.Types as grouping variable so in this case Rich and Poor countries 
# will be colored with different color.

ggplot(df2, aes(x=ES, y=Count.of.ID, fill = ES.Types)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  na.rm=TRUE, colour = "black") +
  geom_text(data = df2, 
            aes(x=ES, y=Count.of.ID, label = Count.of.ID), 
            hjust = 2.5,
            color = "white",
            fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#808080", "#F48024")) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  facet_grid(ES.Types~., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]